# Can issues that occur intermittently on any of the SE sites be posted as bugs here on meta?

Tags: discussion, support, faq-proposed

I noticed that there was a question that was asking for a workaround for an issue that occurred intermittently. When I asked the guy to post the original issue as a bug, he told me he was not sure if he could do it as this issue came only intermittently.

Hence the question:

**Can issues that occur intermittently on any of the SE sites be posted as bugs here on meta?**

Comment: And [this is the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121944/164803) where the issue is mentioned (though the post itself is not about it).  The reason I didn't post a bug report is that I have zero control over when it happens, I cannot reproduce it at all.  I do know though that it has happened to several others too (i.e. not specific to my browser / addons), because they mentioned it in chat.

Comment: @Szabolcs The question now is: Are you going to post that bug?

Comment: I started writing it up, but then I changed my mind.  On Mathematica.SE we are testing a syntax highlighter userscript to be integrated into the site later, and many chat regulars have it installed into their browser.  What if it is the script that is causing the problem?  I'll post about the bug after I manage to rule that possibility out.

Comment: ok... good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Er. Why not? It's a pain if it's hard to reproduce, but a bug that only happens sometimes is still a bug. We can't tell users to just deal with it because sometimes it works

Comment: Thanks a lot for agreeing. I hope this helps the guy I mentioned